# Symfony2 empty form to delete entity

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have an User entity with things like $name, $gender, $email, $password, and so on. This also includes a $postalAddress with a ManyToOne relation to a PostalAddress entity with $city, $postalCode, $streetName and $streetNumber.

I have a registration form in which you can either fill out the whole postalAddress fields or none. This works so far, but here comes the problem:

There is another form, when you already have an account, where you can change your user details. If there is already an address given, and you empty all postalAddress fields, the validator doesnt allow this action even though the UserType/PostalAddressType and validation used are exactly the same. My aim is that you can leave this fields empty to remove the address (set $postalAddress to NULL in the User entity and delete the postalAddress whole, if no other user is referencing to it)

Is there a way to let the user delete an existing address?

Here is the validation.yml:

```
\Entity\User:
    properties:
        postalAddress:
        - Valid: ~
\Entity\PostalAddress:
properties:
    postalCode:
        - NotBlank:
            groups: [flow_createRegistration_step1, default]
        - Type:
            groups: [flow_createRegistration_step1, default]
            type: numeric
            message: "-"
        - Length:
            groups: [flow_createRegistration_step1, default]
            min: 5
            max: 5
            exactMessage: "-"
    city:
        - NotBlank:
            groups: [flow_createRegistration_step1, default]
            message: "field_required"
    streetName:
        - NotBlank:
            groups: [flow_createRegistration_step1, default]
            message: "field_required"
    streetNumber:
        - NotBlank:
            groups: [flow_createRegistration_step1, default]
            message: "field_required"
        - Type:
            groups: [flow_createRegistration_step1, default]
            type: numeric
            message: "-"
```

UserType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    ...
    $builder->add(
        'postalAddress',
        new PostalAddressType(),
        array(
            'label' => false,
            'required' => false
        )
    );
    ...
}
```

PostalAddressType.php:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('streetName', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Straße',
        'required' => true
    ));
    $builder->add('streetNumber', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Nummer',
        'required' => true,
        'max_length' => 5,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'input-mini')
    ));
    $builder->add('postalCode', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'PLZ',
        'required' => true,
        'max_length' => 5,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'input-mini')
    ));
    $builder->add('city', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Ort',
        'required' => true
    ));
    }
```

Comment: I doubt it just with forms, you could add logic in your controller to check for empty postalAddress, remove the associated one, modify the form then check if the form is valid